# times function's values changes outside the loop

Tags: ruby

I write a code that I increment i, 4 times and I added all e's to an array. It works fine if I print the array without using any methods.(Output is: [1,2,3,4]) But if I use to_s method the output turns into"[ ]\x01\x02\x03\x04" which I understand, it probably counts e. But I want my output be : 1,2,3,4 and I don't have any idea how to do this.

So my simplified code looks like this:

```
array = [].to_s
4.times do |e|
  e = e + 1 
  array << e 
end
p array
```

How can I get the output = 1,2,3,4?

Comment: Hint #1: your variable named `array` does *not* contain an array. Hint #2: What do you think the `s` in `to_s` stands for? Hint #3: It does not stand for "array".

Comment: First, I used array.join but the output is the same, that's why I tried to_s. Now that I learn I should use join when printing array. And what would you suggest for printing 1,2,3,4 directly? I used blank array and then added e's bc that's what came to my mind first.

Comment: Mistakes are part of the learning process for every human, so yes @elixir dig more into issues make mistakes like this one, and learn from them as everyone does 

Comment: Thank you @r4cc00n . I'm still trying to improve:)

Comment: Just a note that you could write `Array.new(4) { |i| i+1 } #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: who doesn't @elixir? 

Comment: @CarySwoveland I actually can't because my purpose is not creating an array 1 to 4. I am generating a test and i stands for question numbers and also the number of incorrectly answered questions. If the answer is wrong I add i value to the array and print it with the correct answer but if there's a better option I would like to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy/simple way to do this I think is as below:

```rb
array = []
4.times do |e|
  e = e + 1 
  array << e 
end
p array.join(',')
```

output: `"1,2,3,4"`

The above will print all the items separated by a comma, also this might be helpful [join docs](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/join)

Comment: It might be worth noting that `times` does the actual incrementing here – `e = e + 1` merely adds `1` to its value.

Answer (score 2):

`array = [].to_s` puts the string `'[]'` in the variable `array`. From that point on, the variable is named "array" but its value is not an array at all.

Change the first line to read `array = []` then use [`Array#join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-join) after the loop to concatenate the array values into a string using `,` as separator:

```rb
array = []
4.times do |e|
  array << e + 1 
end 
p array.join ','
```